# Is there a way to grab call/text statistics for an android app?

Tags: android

my team and i are making an android app that is basically an address book. we wanted to add cool statistics like the longest text youve recieved, and how many texts in all you've recieved/sent and same with calls. i could not find a way to access to info. thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the text statistics you can find in SMS/MMS ContentProvider. And all the call statistics also can be found in respective provider.
Use content observers to listen for updates in the corresponding databases if you would like to get informed on any update happening real-time. Otherwise, just read the data when you need it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html

This info should help you get started:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = null;
//This is a query for SMS database
cur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), projection, where,values, sortOrder);

//Do whatever you want with the result 

cur.close();
// This query works with MMS data
cur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://mms"), projection, where, values, sortOrder);

//Process MMS results

cur.close();

//Ask for Call statistics
cur = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, where,values, sortOrder);

//Process the call statistics
cur.close();
```

The databases contain many various fields which you can use to calculate statistics you need. I would recommend to dump the contents of the databases first and look into the fields to understand what information is given. Then you can start creating your sophisticated SQL queries and do necessary calculations.